# window.close() doesn't work on windows phone IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, windows-phone-8

window.close() doesn't work on windows phone with IE.

The tab is opened with :target="_blank" and i try to close it with the following code:

```
<div onclick="window.close();"></div>
```

I tried on IE 11 on windows 8.1 and it worked, without errors, after confirm message.

I tried on Lumia 925, on windows phone emulator,  and it didn't work. The page remains open.

I made the following test page:

http://www.qualcosadafare.it/test/test/anp.php

Have any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Apparently, IE for Windows Phone opens all documents in the same tab. So when you open a new tab with target="_blank", you are in fact closing your current document and replacing it with a new one.

Comment: @GOTO0 So the *Tabs* option is just a history of recently browsed sites? And sites listed there are not opened in a parallel state?

Comment: We use tabs to open detail page and when the page is closed, I don't need to reload the previous page.
Can I force IE to open a new tab?

Comment: @QdF I don't know how. This is a rather bothering peculiarity of IE for WP.

Comment: @malte never meant that. As a user, you can simply open a new tab by clicking the + icon on the bottom. But I couldn't find out how to open a new tab programmatically.

Comment: Many years ago, this used to work in IE: `opener = this; window.close();`, may be worth trying.

Comment: To me its working .. what IE version you are using ?

Comment: I replaced
<a href="cp.php" itemprop="url" target="_blank">
with window.open()

So window.close() works.
I tried on Lumia 630 with Internet Explorer 11.

Explorer doesn't open a new tab, but window.close() doesn't reload the page.
It's ok for me.

Answer (score 0):

Mobile IE only uses one tab. When you use `target="_blank"` you actually aren't opening a new tab, you are opening it in the current tab. There isn't much you can do about this.

Probably the best thing you might be able to do is detect if the user is using IE:

```
function msieversion() {
        var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
        var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");
        if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./))
            return true
        else
            return false
}
```