# MVC4 razor form returns 404 on Windows Phone 8.1 - works on PC with Windows 8.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, windows-phone-8

I have a MVC4 Razor view which has a single form with several submit buttons. A submit button's click is captured by jQuery's `.click()` and the form's action is changed depending on which particular button was clicked. The form is submitted to a new tab (or window) via JavaScript's `form.submit()`. This mechanism works fine in IE 8, 9, 10, 11 and FF 26-30 on a Windows 8 and Windows 8.1 PC.

The problem is occurring with Windows Phone 8 or Windows Phone 8.1 IE. The form is not posted to a new tab or window, and a 404 is returned once submit button is clicked.

Controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[Authorize]
public ActionResult system_A()
{
     //code
}
```

MVC Razor View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("dummyAction", "sso", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "ssoForm", target="_blank" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <input type="submit" id="system_A" class="sso" value="System A" />
    <input type="submit" id="system_B" class="sso" value="System B" />
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$('.sso').click(function () {
        var action = 'sso/' + $(this).prop('id');
        var form=$('#ssoForm');
        $(form).prop('action', action);
        form.submit();
        return false;
});
```

If I remove `target="_blank"` from the form, it works on Windows Phone 8. How can I make this work without removing `target="_blank"`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's something to do with relative vs. absolute urls? Have you tried using an absolute url (the full http://www.myfullsiteurl.com .... url) to see if it makes any difference?

Comment: tried that but no difference. It works on a PC and Android/iPhone but not on Windows Phone 8 or 8.1

Comment: found this (basically IE on Window Phone 8 does not allow programmatic opening of tabs?) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22064152/window-close-doesnt-work-on-windows-phone-ie